# Missing content on a page in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, missing-data

Okay, I'm sure this is obvious but I'm editing a site in Umbraco (I'm supposed to change out a simple email address), and I believe I have found the page to edit but in the Body Text Box there isn't any text to clearly state "THIS IS THE PAGE TO EDIT!"

I'm at a stand still because of this but I'm hoping that someone can help me. I'm sure its simple but...

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? Usually Umbraco stores the pages in the same structure as the front end. So a page called /contact-us/thanks in the back office will be: home node > contact-us > thanks

Comment: Yeah. This is the  structure: Home > Technology >  Technology Solutions >   Page > Page > Thanks. The 2nd "Page" in this structure (the page I'm looking at) is there but the body text is missing altogether.

Comment: maybe the text is not in the body text box then but in the template itself you might need to check where the text you want to change is located in the template (or the umbraco field)

Comment: Have a look in the properties tab of the second page to see what template it's using, and check the template to see the part where it's adding the body text. Can you update your post to include that code?

Comment: Thanks for comments/answer's with such limited details.  Found out it was a static page that was linked to an umbraco template.